# Foundry Astar zkEVM Deployment

Tags: foundry, astar

#### Hola

I'm Frank. I have an Issue.
I wanna deploy something on the zkEVM from Astar.
I'm using foundry.

I guess my `--rpc-url` argument is wrong

Thats my command:

```
forge create --rpc-url https://rpc.zkatana.gelato.digital  --private-key $env.ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY --etherscan-api-key $env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY --verify src/Counter.sol:Counter
```

Thats my recieved Output

```
[⠃] Compiling...
No files changed, compilation skipped
Error: 
custom error: EIP-1559 not activated
```

Thats my quick chatGPT answer

```
This error message indicates that the function or feature you are trying to use requires the activation of EIP-1559, but it has not been activated or enabled. EIP-1559 is an upgrade proposal for the Ethereum network that aims to improve transaction pricing and user experience. To resolve this error, you may need to update or configure your software to enable EIP-1559 support.
```

I don't think this is true.

> An Example of my [Desired Result (Sepolia Edition)](https://sepolia.etherscan.io/address/0x5aa0b5ee61195075df5626244533838d32a097ba#code)

**Any Help/Reccomendation/..?**

#### Cheers ️

Ressources:
[Astar Hardhat Wiki](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/zkEVM/smart-contracts/using-hardhat)
[My Stupid Contract](https://github.com/FrankBevr/key3D/blob/d2aa4c84a4b53be252a1b67ec4ecd8ac3028ce1d/SmartContract/Ramen/src/Counter.sol)

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no Etherscan on zKatana. zKatana uses Blockscout as the block explorer. Therefore you can't use `etherscan-api-key` and you can't verify contract from the command line.
2. zkEVM does not use EIP-1559 yet, check the zKatana [docs](https://docs.astar.network/docs/build/zkEVM/fee). But you can work around this problem by adding `--legacy` in your command.

```
forge create --rpc-url https://rpc.zkatana.gelato.digital --private-key $PK src/Counter.sol:Counter --legacy
```